# POST no save to model. return "this field is required" error on Django

Tags: python, django

Hi friends I am new for Django
I want to make a form with bootstrap.

When I click submit Button  Post Data is

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['mjzoKZ1GPuHMCR6LQwNpUxDW0Y1KyxRgySSynPSOU7eHK8Zlm5dgqvWwhXpD3F0M'], '<input type="text" name="borclu" maxlength="36" required id="id_borclu">': ['asfasf'], '<input type="email" name="borclu_mail" maxlength="25" required id="id_borclu_mail">': ['asdasd'], '<textarea name="borcluAdres" cols="40" rows="10" maxlength="80" required id="id_borcluAdres">\r\n</textarea>': ['asdasd'], '<input type="text" name="borcluTelefon" maxlength="11" required id="id_borcluTelefon">': ['asdasd'], '<input type="number" name="tutar" required id="id_tutar">': ['asdasd'], '<input type="text" name="cek_tarih" required id="id_cek_tarih">': ['12-02-2019']}>
```

But data no saved to model

My model like that;

```py
class cekler(models.Model):

    borclu=models.CharField(max_length=36,verbose_name="Keşideci")
    borcluAdres=models.TextField(max_length=80,verbose_name="Keşideci Adresi")
    borclu_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=25,verbose_name="Keşideci E Posta Adresi")
    borcluTelefon=models.CharField(max_length=11,verbose_name="Keşideci Telefon")

    tutar=models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Tutar")
    bankalar = (
        ('Ziraat Bankası', 'Ziraat Bankası'),
        ('YapıKredi Bankası', 'YapıKredi Bankası'),
        ('Vakıflar Bankası', 'Vakıflar Bankası'),
        ('Teb', 'TEB'),
    )
    banka=models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=bankalar, verbose_name="Banka Adı:")
    cek_tarih=models.DateField(verbose_name="Çek Tarihi")

    son_tarih = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def _get_gecen_gun(self):
        "Returns the person's full name."
        day=date.today()-self.cek_tarih
        ggun = str(day)
        ggun = ggun.split(' ')[0]
        return '%s' % (ggun)

    gecenGun = property(_get_gecen_gun)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.borclu

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.son_tarih = self.cek_tarih + datetime.timedelta(days=80)
        super(cekler, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
```

My Form.py;

```py
from django import forms
from .models import cekler

class CekForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=cekler
        fields=[
            'borclu',
            'borcluAdres',
            'borclu_mail',
            'borcluTelefon',
            'tutar',
            'banka',
            'cek_tarih',

        ]
```

My Template

```
<form method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
<div class="container">

 <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Keşideci Adı</label>

      <input type="text" name='{{ form.borclu }}' class="form-control"  >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputPassword4">Borçlu Mail</label>
      <input type="text" name='{{ form.borclu_mail }}' class="form-control"  >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress">Borçlu Adres</label>
  <input type="text" name='{{ form.borcluAdres }}' class="form-control"  >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress2">Borçlu Telefon</label>
    <input type="text" name='{{ form.borcluTelefon }}' class="form-control"  >
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputCity">Tutar</label>
      <input type="text" name='{{ form.tutar }}' class="form-control"  >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="inputState">Banka</label>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
            {% for value in form.banka %}
            <option >{{ value }}</option>
            {% endfor %}

      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
      <label for="inputZip">Çek Tarihi</label>
       <input type="text" name='{{ form.cek_tarih }}' class="form-control"  >
    </div>
  </div>

<a href="{% url 'home' %}"> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Ekle"></a>
</div>






</form>
```

I think problem from my Bootstrap implementation. Before this implemantation I use form with 'form.as_p' and it was correct.

Now when I click button anything happen. No error. But data no save on my model.

Comment: hi, can you post the view of this form in the question too?

Comment: Try just using `name='borclu'` instead of `name={{ form.borclu }}` and so on for other fields too. Make sure the value of name attribute matches the field name specified in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting the wrong thing in your template. You should be able to see from the submitted data that each field has some HTML as its key, which is obviously wrong.

Instead of `name='{{ form.borclu }}'` etc you should probably do `name='{{ form.borclu.name }}'`.